# app unfortunately stopped while changing fragment in navigation drawer because of handler

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-handler

I have used navigation drawer in my app. There are two fragments. One is for profile and another is for feedback. In profile fragment, I need to call a function every 5 seconds. So, I used a handler. Here, onStart works for calling the function every 5 seconds. I think, this is the main reason for the app crashing while changing fragments. If I comment out onStart and onPause, everything goes alright. How can I handle this problem?

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

private ListView listView;
TextView textView;

Handler h = new Handler();
int delay = 5000; // 5 seconds
Runnable runnable;

public ProfileFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);

    textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewUsername);
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    //sendRequest();
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    //you can set the title for your toolbar here for different fragments different titles
    getActivity().setTitle("Profile");
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
//start handler as activity become visible
    h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //do something
            sendRequest();
            runnable=this;

            h.postDelayed(runnable, delay);
        }
    }, delay);

    super.onStart();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    h.removeCallbacks(runnable); //stop handler when activity not visible
    super.onPause();
}

private void sendRequest(){

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Config.LOCATION_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d("location", response.toString());
                    showJSON(response);
                    //Toast.makeText(getContext().getApplicationContext(), "Data loaded successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext().getApplicationContext(),error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
private void showJSON(String json){
    ParseJSON pj = new ParseJSON(json);
    pj.parseJSON();
    CustomList cl = new CustomList(this.getActivity(), ParseJSON.ids,ParseJSON.busNames,ParseJSON.busLocations,ParseJSON.times);
    listView.setAdapter(cl);
  }
}
```

Comment: please post the stack strace from LogCat.

Comment: Tell me when does the app crash and what kind of  an exception is thrown.

Comment: app crashes while changing fragments.

Comment: Firstly call it in Parent Class not in fragment and secondly in background.

Comment: didn't get your point.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use TimerTask Class instead of the handler to do a task which is to be repeated after certain time:

```
TimerTask tasknew = new TimerScheduleFixedRateDelay();
Timer timer = new Timer();

// scheduling the task at fixed rate delay
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(tasknew,500,1000);      
}
// this method performs the task
public void run() {
//Do your task here in runOnUiThread(); 
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: how to resolve this "TimerScheduleFixedRateDelay" ? should I import something?

Comment: If I use TimerTask, app crashed as like before while changing fragment.